# Spring Data - get last record from the table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I would like to retrieve the last record from `Settings` table.

I have `SettingsRepository` with standard methods implemented by Spring Data. How to write a method (or a query) to retrieve last row from the given table?

```
interface SettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Settings, Long> {
    // ?
}
```

Comment: what does 'last' mean to you?

Comment: Order table reversed on id if you use a sequence, or creation_date if you use auditing, then limit to 1 record.

Comment: I would like to do sth like this: "select * from settings order by id desc limit 1"

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should use `findTopByOrderByIdDesc()`

This is called named query, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Comment: I would like to see the result when 50 threads insert into the same table...

Comment: @madhairsilence it's called Spring Boot Named Query. Check the docs...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Comment: strangely, its really important to name the method like it is above, Despite it saying findTopBy... and then Not specifying what to find it by and proceeding straight on to OrderBy and then having the field name, and lastly ending with Desc; this is the way.

Comment: i use findTopByOrderByIdDesc and i have a id property in my table object class. but always receive null. i have a row in database.

Answer (score 6):

There is no specific function to get the last record.

You can, however, order in reverse (DESC on ID, for example - assuming there's an ID) and get the first record.

EDIT: As per @MountainKing's suggestion in the comments below, you can use `findTopByOrderByIdDesc()`

Comment: I know how to do this in SQL, but how to do this using Spring Data?

Comment: how do you mean there is no specific funcion to do this? You can use findTopByOrderByIdDesc()

Comment: @MountainKing I guess I could've worded it more precise. What I meant was: there is no function to directly get the last result -without- ordering descending (that I know of).

Comment: Thanks @MountainKing, that's what I've been looking for